# How to give index id to my uploaded json file in FastAPI?

Tags: python, json, indexing, fastapi

```json
[
  {
    "B4": 14,
    "B5": 12
  },
  {
    "B4": 58,
    "B5": 54
  },
  {
    "B4": 26,
    "B5": 65
  }
]
```

I want to create index ID in my uploaded json file. The json file look like as in the image. I want it to be like the following:

```json
[
  1: {
       "B4": 14,
       "B5": 12
     },
  2: {
       "B4": 58,
       "B5": 54
     },
  3: {
       "B4": 26,
       "B5": 65
     }
]
```

It's just to do some calculations for each set and display the results.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please don't add irrelevant tags (i.e., `pandas`). `[ 1: { "B4": 14, "B5": 12 }, 2: { "B4": 58, "B5": 54 }, 3: { "B4": 26, "B5": 65 } ]` would not be valid json. Perhaps you are looking for `{'1': { "B4": 14, "B5": 12 }, '2': { "B4": 58, "B5": 54 }, '3': { "B4": 26, "B5": 65 } }` (json keys need to be strings)? Also, please share what you have tried so far. SO is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import your JSON file, extract each element and add it to a dictionary with its key as index. Convert the dictionary to a JSON object and write it on to a JSON file.
Here is the sample code below:

```
import json
f = open('data.json')
data = json.load(f)
updated_data = dict()
for index, item in enumerate(data, start=1):
    updated_data[index] = item
json_object = json.dumps(updated_data)
with open("updated_data.json", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(json_object)
```

Output:

```
{"1": {"B4": 14, "B5": 12}, "2": {"B4": 58, "B5": 54}, "3": {"B4": 26, "B5": 65}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The list you shared as output is not valid as list cannot be a key value pair. Did you mean this - a dict of dicts?

```
{
  1: {
       "B4": 14,
       "B5": 12
     },
  2: {
       "B4": 58,
       "B5": 54
     },
}
```

To get that -

```
import json
with open("file/path.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)  # Output a list of dict
    dict_with_index = dict(zip(range(1,len(data) + 1), data))
```